# Constructing quines (self-reproducing functions)

Tags: r, quine

Has anyone constructed a quine ("A program that generates a copy of its own source text as its complete output": [http://www.nyx.net/~gthompso/quine.htm](http://www.nyx.net/%7Egthompso/quine.htm)) in R?  (The [quine] tag pulls up lots of examples in Python, Java, ... but apparently none in R.)

```
f <- function() { body() }
```

comes close:

```
> f()
{
    body()
}
```

but lacks the name of the function.

How about the shortest possibility?  Most obfuscated?

**edit**: from the variety of answers below, it seems that there are a variety of ways to define self-referentiality and the environment in which it must occur:

- within the R environment: function `->` function (@bill_080)
- within the OS/shell environment: program `->` program [more or less equivalent to program `->` text]: (@kohske)
- other: function `->` text (@JoshUlrich, @James, problem as defined above)

Notes:

- The [thread from R-help pointed out by @Spacedman](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-May/033730.html) (which seems to emphasize obfuscation over brevity) suggests that `identical(quine,quine())` is a good test case, although it's tricky because environments get carried along: `identical(quine,quine(),ignore.environment=TRUE)` might be easier.
- A recent (Oct 2015) [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304012314/http://xavier.nayrac.eu/2015/10/10/a-quine-in-r/) provides another answer ...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is the shortest I can come up with:

```
> "f" <- function() call("<-", "f", f)
> f()
"f" <- function () 
call("<-", "f", f)
```

Answer (score 21):

Here is a real Quine, **a program** (not a function) that generates a copy of its own source text as its complete output.

On console,

```
# y1.R is a quine program
$ cat y1.R
(function(x){cat(x);cat('(');cat(intToUtf8(0x0022));cat(x);cat(intToUtf8(0x0022));cat(')')})("(function(x){cat(x);cat('(');cat(intToUtf8(0x0022));cat(x);cat(intToUtf8(0x0022));cat(')')})")

# execute y1.R and show output
$ /usr/bin/R --vanilla --slave < y1.R
(function(x){cat(x);cat('(');cat(intToUtf8(0x0022));cat(x);cat(intToUtf8(0x0022));cat(')')})("(function(x){cat(x);cat('(');cat(intToUtf8(0x0022));cat(x);cat(intToUtf8(0x0022));cat(')')})")

# save the output of the execution of y1
$ /usr/bin/R --vanilla --slave < y1.R > y2.R

# compare input and output -- exactly same.
$ diff y1.R y2.R
```

probably this is not the shortest one.

**UPDATED:**

and slightly shorter version:

```
(function(x){cat(x,'(',d<-intToUtf8(0x0022),x,d,')',sep='')})("(function(x){cat(x,'(',d<-intToUtf8(0x0022),x,d,')',sep='')})")
```

Answer (score 6):

Using what `body` does as inspiration, `call` can be used to reproduce the calling command:

```
f <- function () 
{
    call("<-", as.name(as.character(sys.calls()[[1]])), sys.function(sys.parent()))
}
```

Which outputs:

```
> f()
f <- function () 
{
    call("<-", as.name(as.character(sys.calls()[[1]])), sys.function(sys.parent()))
}
```

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich Oops, fixed it now. As an added bonus the added complexity makes it less easy to read and therefore more obfuscated! ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a function that returns a function.....maybe this?

```
junk <- function(...) {
  function(...) {
    structure(junk(...))
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
> junk()

function(...) {
    structure(junk(...))
  }
<environment: 01ef8e50>


> boo <- junk(999)
> boo

function(...) {
    structure(junk(...))
  }
<environment: 020e1048>


>dput(boo)

function (...) 
{
    structure(junk(...))
}
```

Comment: Some useful links: http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~ihaka/downloads/lexical.pdf     http://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~ihaka/downloads/Compstat-2008.pdf

Comment: I like this, but the specific definition given above is "a function that generates a copy of its own source text", even though "a function that generates a copy of itself" is closer to the spirit of self-reproducibility.  In your example the returned function is not quite identical to the original function although perhaps you could replace `inp` with `...` and it would be?

Comment: @Ben B, You're right.  `inp` was from me screwing around trying to extend the capabilities.   I'll fix it.

Comment: Since this doesn't really answer the question, maybe I should delete it?

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure if this "counts" from a quine perspective (I stumbled across this question while trying to verify if it does), the script

```
function(){}
```

will output `function(){}`. This works on the same principle as Joshua Ulrich's answer, just pared down to the essentials.