# Is function(){} a true quine?

Tags: r, quine

After poking around on the internet I wasn't able to find anyone who had written a quine in R (Edit: since writing this, have found several on SO, but am still interested in this one). So I figured I'd try my hand at coming up with one myself. My result was the (surprisingly short) code:

```
function(){}
```

which will output `function(){}` when run. This takes advantage of the fact that a function name without parens or arguments after it will return the function's source code.

However, a program that "looks at itself" is not generally considered a true quine. There are two things I realized I don't understand in the course of trying to decide whether I'd written a "real" quine: (1) What constitutes a program "looking at itself" (from a quine standpoint) beyond use of file i/o and (2) the extent to which `function(){}` (or similar commands like `logical(0)`) are self referential when they print themselves. The former seems to be too subjective for SO, but I was hoping for some clarification on the latter. So...

When I run `function(){}`, what exactly is happening that causes it to print its own "source code"? For example, is R loading an empty function into a local environment, evaluating that function, and then looking back at the code that defined it to print? Or, is it just looking at `function(){}` and echoing its definition right away? Is there a fundamental difference between this and

```
f<-function(){cat("f<-");print(f);cat("f()")}
f()
```

in terms of how they both print themselves when run?

Comment: I think it would be cheating because the REPL is implicitly calling `print()` for you; your source code is not printing itself.

Comment: I've never heard the word 'quine', but R functions are fun, maybe something like `f <- (function() this <- function() print(attr(this,'srcref')))()` then `f()`

Comment: Any anonymous function definition is a quine following your logic. Actually, the function you are defining is not executed, but just printed, as @MrFlick said.

Comment: or maybe `f <- function() print(attr(get('f'), 'srcref'))` would make more sense

Comment: R tends to print a lot of things verbatim, `NULL`, `espression(1)`, `character(0)`, so any of these could be put in a script on their own and their "output" (in the console) would consist of their source code. Ensuring that the output is a separate file... now there's more of a puzzle.

Comment: This is interesting but I'm not sure it's on-topic: it's not a programming question, but a question about the *definition* of a quine, which is prone to opinionated answers ... more discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495962/constructing-quines-self-reproducing-functions)

Comment: I wrote a quine in R [here](http://xavier.nayrac.eu/2015/10/13/a-quine-n-r-the-return/) and there is another one on rosetta code

Answer (score 1):

You don't completely get what's going on here. Actually, the code

```
function(){}
```

doesn't do anything apart from constructing a function without arguments and body, returning it and deleting it immediately after it's returned. Its output would be `NULL`, so doesn't "recreate itself".

The output you see in the console, is not the output given by `function(){}` but by `print.function`. This is the S3 method that takes care of showing a function object in the console. What you actually do, is:

```
a <- function(){}
print(a)
rm(a)
```

A true R quine would be something like this:

```
m<-"m<-0;cat(sub(0,deparse(m),m))";cat(sub(0,deparse(m),m))
```

See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29) for this and other examples

Answer (score 0):

This is not a true quine as it does not print anything to stdout. Whole point of Quine is that it can reproduce itself by printing. Program must create a new file or output in stdout containing its exact code.

Example of a javascript quine would be:

```
(function a(){console.log(`(${a}())`)}())
```

Answer (score 0):

`(function(x) print(substitute(x(x))))(function(x) print(substitute(x(x))))`

Comment: Is this an example quine? I don't think the question was looking for a valid quine but whether their particular program counted

Comment: I agree you're right, nevertheless i'm not sure if this question is not off topic.